# mysql source, how to find the line number of error?

Tags: mysql

In mysql, I issue  source mysource.sql
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
Is there way to get the exact location of the error?
Is line 1 really line 1?

the file is large. You can give -1 but I am really looking for a setting or a tool that help in that.

Comment: What does your SQL file look like?

Comment: What does line 1 look like, at least?

Comment: Depending how large the .sql file, you could use a program like [notepad2](http://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html) and open the it and it will have syntax highlighting to catch a possible quote mismatch. otherwise, break the statements out in to separate lines if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of mysql> source mysource.sql # you can use command prompt with --verbose option for more helpful output.

```
# mysql --verbose test < mysource.sql
```